# Elasticsearch index: /fulltext_2/doc/xxxxx caused blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete

Tags: database, elasticsearch, indexing

Can somebody tell me please what means this error? **Elasticsearch index: /fulltext_2/doc/xxxxx caused blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete** I have a local Elasticsearch server. I have created an index fulltext_2 and I would like to insert some documents. There is a PHP script to do it. Why I can not insert any items to database if I have permission to create an index? What is going on? Thank you for any help.

Comment: maybe not enough space? what does `GET _cluster/settings` and `GET _cat/allocation` return back?

Comment: You are right, not enough space was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error running this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"index":{"blocks":{"read_only_allow_delete":"false"}}}'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/fulltext_2/_settings' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"index":{"blocks":{"read_only_allow_delete":"false"}}}'
```